# Composing a regexp to highlight folder extensions differently

Tags: dired, regular-expressions

I am having difficulties composing a regexp that will highlight certain *folder* extensions -- **including the preceding dot** -- with colors that are different than the rest of the folder -- e.g., `.app` would be colored red; and `.git` would be colored blue.

Examples:

- The folder `Emacs.app` would be colorized with `Emacs` being a gray color and `.app` would be a red color.
- The folder `.0.context-menu.git` would be colorized with `.0.context-menu` being a gray color and `.git` would be a blue color.

I have a regexp that gets me from the left margin all the way to the beginning of the folder -- the variable for that regexp is named `folder-listing-before-filename-regexp`.

The problem I am having is that the regex `.*` swallows up the folder extensions.  If I add `[^.]`, that prevents me from using the dot later on with extensions like `.app` and `.git` -- I want the extension to include the dot when colored.

The regexp that leads up to the folder looks like this:

```
(defvar folder-listing-before-filename-regexp
  (concat
    "\\(^ +d[slrwxt+-]+\\)"    ;; 1  permissions
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 2
    "\\([0-9]+\\|\s+[0-9]+\\)" ;; 3  some small numbers
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 4
    "\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)"          ;; 5  group
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 6
    "\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)"          ;; 7  user
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 8
    "\\([\s0-9.kKMGT]+\\)"     ;; 9  size
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 10
    "\\([0-9-]+\\)"            ;; 11 date
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 12
    "\\([0-9:]+\\)"            ;; 13 time
    "\\(\s\\)"))               ;; 14
```

Here is some test data:

```
  drwxr-xr-x  79 HOME staff 2.7K 10-30-2014 16:42:18 .
  drwxr-xr-x  27 HOME staff  918 10-28-2014 13:08:59 ..
  drwxr-xr-x 162 HOME staff 5.4K 10-11-2014 11:34:16 .0.apel_flim_simi
  drwxr-xr-x 432 HOME staff  15K 10-29-2014 15:37:44 .0.backup
  drwxr-xr-x   5 HOME staff  170 10-19-2014 09:34:37 .0.context-menu.git
  drwxr-xr-x   5 HOME staff  170 10-19-2014 13:06:36 .0.dired-read-filename.git
  drwx------   4 HOME staff  136 04-29-2014 17:40:13 .0.eshell
  drwxr-xr-x   3 HOME staff  102 10-11-2014 10:29:03 .0.gh
  drwxr-xr-x   5 HOME staff  170 10-09-2014 21:16:35 .0.lorg-calendar.git
  drwxr-xr-x   5 HOME staff  170 10-09-2014 20:06:09 .0.lorg-search.git
  drwxr-xr-x  10 HOME staff  340 01-31-2014 19:37:31 .0.mail
  drwxr-xr-x  25 HOME staff  850 10-14-2014 13:23:31 .0.snippets
  drwxr-xr-x  23 HOME staff  782 12-03-2013 17:15:50 .0.sound
  drwxr-xr-x  27 HOME staff  918 10-18-2014 11:53:56 .0.sources
  drwxr-xr-x  67 HOME staff 2.3K 05-05-2014 23:19:12 .0.w3m
  drwxr-xr-x 146 HOME staff 4.9K 09-08-2014 10:54:40 .0.wl
  drwxr-xr-x   3 HOME staff  102 06-03-2014 11:37:02 Emacs.app
  drwxr-xr-x   3 HOME staff  102 06-01-2014 10:39:02 Emacs_06_01_2014.app
  drwxr-xr-x   3 HOME staff  102 10-01-2014 07:31:45 Emacs_10_01_2014.app
  drwxr-xr-x 195 HOME staff 6.5K 10-18-2014 12:06:25 bin
  drwxr-xr-x   3 HOME staff  102 06-26-2013 07:59:44 etc
  drwxr-xr-x  10 HOME staff  340 09-30-2014 18:07:42 include
  drwxr-xr-x   9 HOME staff  306 06-05-2013 22:50:05 info
  drwxr-xr-x  27 HOME staff  918 10-18-2014 12:06:42 lib
  drwxr-xr-x  12 HOME staff  408 09-30-2014 18:10:42 libexec
  drwxr-xr-x   4 root staff  136 09-30-2014 18:07:42 man
  drwxr-xr-x   4 root staff  136 09-30-2014 18:10:42 sbin
  drwxr-xr-x   9 HOME staff  306 09-30-2014 18:10:42 share
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you tried looking into other options? Such as [Dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/DiredPlus)?

Comment: Why would `[^.]*` prevent you from using the dot? Something like `[^.]*\\(\\..*\\)` should match your request and group the entire extension including the dot. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: @Malabarba -- your suggestion almost does it, with the exception of the folders beginning with a dot -- e.g., `.0.context-menu.git`  I'll work on it a little later on this evening using your example as a starting point.

Comment: I see. And does `.*\\(\\.[^.]*\\)$` not work either? (I'm not at the pc right now so I can't test myself).

Comment: @King Shimkus -- yes, thank you -- the regex for the permission colors and file size are from Dired+, but I broke some of the functionality by adding a custom time-style.  My custom time-style is also not compatible with `directory-listing-before-filename-regexp`.  Dired mode is not designed for a custom time-style like the one I'm using, so I'm essentially creating a custom version of dired-mode.

Comment: @Malabarba -- Yes, I think that does it!  I'll report back later this evening when I've done a little more testing.  Thank you.

Comment: @Malabarba -- I have a working draft of a few categories with slightly different regexp for each category, and a catch-all category that incorporates a custom list consisting of anything not previously handled.  However, I have not yet been able to compose one whopper regexp for all situations -- e.g., `\\(?:stuff\\(more-stuff\\)\\)?\\(?:misc\\(more-misc\\)\\)?$`.  I'd like to please leave this thread open for a couple of days to do some more experimenting and then post a working draft as an edit to my question.  Thanks again for putting me on the right track -- greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: @lawlist I may be wrong, but it looks like you're using question marks when you actually need a `\\|`.

Comment: @Malabarba -- I was hoping to do something like 15 (if matched) will be red, 16 (if matched) will be blue, 17 (if matched) will be green, and so on.  If I use `\\|`, then they will all be the same color -- unless it's somehow possible to use `\\(something\\)` in conjunction with `\\|` -- I've never seen an example that uses both.  However, my initial attempts at putting possible matches with question marks haven't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is just a tweak to Dired+ -- adopting the same manner to highlight folder extensions as is already done with file extensions; with the additional tweak to the beginning regexp to get me over to the files / folders.  My custom time-style of `ls` is not compatible with dired-mode or the corresponding regexp in files.el, so I composed my own regexp.  The section below relating to `diredp-font-lock-keywords-1` is just the relevant excerpt.

Over the next few days, I'll continue to think about the regexp proposed by @Malabarba `.*\\(\\.[^.]*\\)$` to see if I can create a whopper regexp that covers the majority of situations.  I ended up with about 5 different regexp strings, which is not as clean as Dired+ presently offers.

```
(defvar folder-listing-before-filename-regexp
  (concat
    "\\(^ +d[slrwxt+-]+\\)"    ;; 1  permissions
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 2
    "\\([0-9]+\\|\s+[0-9]+\\)" ;; 3  some small numbers
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 4
    "\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)"          ;; 5  user
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 6
    "\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)"          ;; 7  group
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 8
    "\\([\s0-9.kKMGT]+\\)"     ;; 9  size
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 10
    "\\([0-9-]+\\)"            ;; 11 date
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 12
    "\\([0-9:]+\\)"            ;; 13 time
    "\\(\s\\)"))               ;; 14

(defvar file-listing-before-filename-regexp
  (concat
    "\\(^ +[^d][slrwxt+-]+\\)" ;; 1  permissions
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 2
    "\\([0-9]+\\|\s+[0-9]+\\)" ;; 3  some small numbers
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 4
    "\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)"          ;; 5  user
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 6
    "\\([a-zA-Z]+\\)"          ;; 7  group
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 8
    "\\([\s0-9.kKMGT]+\\)"     ;; 9  size
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 10
    "\\([0-9-]+\\)"            ;; 11 date
    "\\(\s\\)"                 ;; 12
    "\\([0-9:]+\\)"            ;; 13 time
    "\\(\s\\)"))               ;; 14

(defvar diredp-font-lock-keywords-1
  (list
    '("[^ .]\\.\\(git\\)$" 1 'diredp-git-face t)
    '("[^ .]\\.\\(app\\)$" 1 'diredp-app-face t)

  (list folder-listing-before-filename-regexp
    (list "\\(.+\\)$" nil nil (list 0 diredp-dir-priv 'keep t))) ; folder-name

  (list file-listing-before-filename-regexp
    (list "\\(.+\\)$" nil nil (list 0 diredp-file-name 'keep t))) ; file-name
  ))
```